# Twice UK business visitor visa refusal because of large deposit, what next?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I have applied for a UK visa business visitor twice and both of them have been refused.

I'd like to declare that my request was real with an invitation letter from my employer, hr letter and bank statement summary.

some of my friends who traveled to UK before advised me to borrow some money and deposit it to my account to look better, but it was a very bad idea.

My application has been refused for the first time because the clearance officer wants to see the salary transactions in my account and my marriage evidence.

in the second application I have submitted the bank statement in detailed beside my marriage evidence but it also refused for the second time because of the large deposit prior of my application.

I cannot tell them I have borrowed this money as you know.

shall I wait for six months for example and submit a fresh bank statement with a fresh application or it will be a waste of time?

### will they treat the third application with its merits or they will consider the previous refusal reasons and will ask for the origin of the large deposit again?

I have added the reasons of the first and second refusals.

The first refusal reasons are:

> You have applied to travel to the UK on business for a one month trip
>   for training. You have indicated that your employers will fund your
>   proposed visit and that the cost to you personally will be £300.”  “To
>   demonstrate your circumstances you have submitted an employment letter
>   from ... and an invitation letter from ... along with your bank
>   summary certificate which shows no transactions or income. From these
>   documents I am not satisfied that you are in receipt of your stated
>   monthly income or therefore that your circumstances in Egypt are as
>   stated.”  “I have considered the evidence and information submitted in
>   your application; and on the balance of probabilities I am not
>   satisfied your circumstances are as claimed and, therefore, I am not
>   satisfied as to your intentions in wishing to travel to the United
>   Kingdom now. As a result I am not satisfied that you are genuinely
>   seeking entry as a business visitor or intend to leave the UK at the
>   end of your visit. Paragraph V 4.2 (a) (c) of the immigration Rules.
>   In order to assess your intentions to leave the UK at the end of your
>   visit, as required by the Immigration Rules, I have taken into account
>   that you have not demonstrated any family remaining in Egypt. You have
>   shown no assets or property in Egypt. In assessing your ties to Egypt
>   I consider that these are therefore limited, and amount to your stated
>   employment only. As a consequence I do not consider that you have
>   demonstrated, with the evidence presented, that you will leave the UK
>   upon completion of your visit.”

the second refusal reasons are :

> you state that you are emplyed by ... and you intend to travel to the
>   UK for business meetings. To demonstrate this you have provided a
>   letter from ... given the fact that your meetingz were due to commence
>   10 days after your visa application was submitted and in the absence
>   of any further information confirming a change in the dates of your
>   trip. I am not satisfied that you genuinely seeking entry as a
>   business visitor.  you state that you recive a monthly income of ...
>   and you have not declared cany other income. To demonstrate your
>   personal circumstances you have provided a bank statement in your name
>   with clothing balance ... I note that the balance of the account was
>   inflated by a a cash  deposit of ... on ... . Given the fact that this
>   deposit equates to 10 times your monthly income. It is reasonable to
>   expect you to demonstrate the origin of these  funds, you have not
>   done so and as a result.  I am not satisfied that you have provided an
>   accurate account of your personal circumstances and as a result I
>   caused to doubt your intentions for traveling to the UK  at this time.
>
> I have considered the evidence and information submitted in your
>   application; and on the balance of probabilities I am not satisfied
>   your circumstances are as claimed and, therefore I am not satisfied as
>   result I am not satisfied that you are genuinely seeking entry as a
>   business visitor or intend to leave the UK at the end of your visit. 
>   Paragraph V 4.2 ( a ) ( c ) of the immigration Rules.  Future
>   applications Any future UK applications you make will be considered in
>   thier individual merits,  however you are likely to be refused unless
>   the circumstances of your application change.

Comment: Above all, being honest is the best option with visas :/
"Shall I wait" is very subjective - as per our [help], it's probably best to remove/reword that, editing your question, or it may get closed as subjective.

Comment: Can you give us some information on what the purpose of this visit is?
Also, can you lease provide the exact refusal reasons given.

Comment: Dear Mark Mayo,  thanks for your editing my question.

Comment: They will have refused you on some specific grounds, something like `4.2 appendix Y` or similar. We need to know those exact ones to be able to help

Comment: Dear CMaster & Gavravarr, The purpose of the visit is for training of production for a new product.  I have added the reasons in the main post.

Comment: @Alexander you need to include the final sentences of your refusal notice. Where it gives the legal grounds for your refusal...  Per Gagravarr (to whom thanks) it will undoubtedly be something in 4.2 of Appendix V.  Please edit your question to give the ENTIRE notice, thanks

Comment: @Gayot Fow, I added the last paragraph in the notice. Shall it help?

Comment: @Alexander yes that helps. Always better to include the ENTIRE notice. Now you can expect an answer.

Answer (score 5):

You applied for a UK visa twice (apparently back-to-back) and used a funds parking strategy, i.e., someone parked funds in your account with the intent of making you appear to be more solvent than you actually are. It is a type of dishonesty and they do not like it, but worse, it damages your credibility going forward.

Showing a hefty bank balance is helpful, but it's only about 20% of what they are looking for.  A much heavier weight, say 80%, is given to periodic, predictable flows in and out of the account that show a durable economic connection to your base, in your case Egypt. I.e., that you are a stable person with substantial ties to Egypt.  The ECO pointed out that your accounts did not tie out to the job you claimed to have and this was a show-stopper in its own right.  So the funds parking strategy was doomed from the outset.

They got you on V 4.2 (a) and (c) on both applications. In this context it means they concluded that you were not a bona fide applicant and that would most likely go underground when you got here and there are no ties to Egypt that would motivate you to return to Egypt.

To make matters more complex, you applied back-to-back without fixing the reasons they refused the first time. They wanted to see a stable job situation and a proper series of bank statements that tied everything together. You gave neither of those and they refused again.  Now matters are worse.

**"I cannot tell them I have borrowed this money as you know."**

Why not? If you borrowed the money they would appreciate knowing the details about it because that preserves your credibility. It's far better to get refused on technical grounds rather than funds parking because credibility problems are hard to fix.

**"shall I wait for six months for example and submit a fresh bank statement with a fresh application or it will be a waste of time?"**

It's a waste of time. As I pointed out having a large sum of money in your bank account is only a small part of the picture.  The bank statements need to map in to your job and living expenses with periodic deposits and predictable withdrawals.  The higher priority is convincing them that you are employed because they didn't believe what you told them about your job: *From these documents I am not satisfied that you are in receipt of your stated monthly income or therefore that your circumstances in Egypt are as stated.*

**"will they treat the third application with its merits or they will consider the previous refusal reasons and will ask for the origin of the large deposit again?"**

They will always want to know the origin of all deposits, part of their charter is to assure that you have obtained your money legally, not a drug dealer, trafficker, prostitute, smuggler and so on...

Even though they say future applications are assessed on their merit, they will take your previous refusals into account and thus will be informed that you're a person who is not entirely transparent about their circumstances. That will hurt you.  Moreover, I don't think six months is adequate to get into a believable employment situation and establish substantial ties to Egypt, but perhaps it's possible.

Comment: many thanks for your answer,  but the problem is everything in my two application was and still real except this issue of parking money.  I have a stable job with a stable salary and wife and kids and home (all this evidence submitted) and fixed the reasons of the first refusal.  Then the issue of this large deposit showed up and led to the second refusal.

Comment: My thoughts is : if I return this large deposit back to its owner and wait for example for six, nine months then submitted a fresh bank statement with opening amount and clothing amount related only to my salary (without any large deposit) beside every other supporting docs. Is that will be okay.  Or it will lead to a third refusal because of the previous two refusal?

Comment: We are not the Tribunal and cannot second guess if they decided correctly or incorrectly. We can only read the refusal notices and interpret them.  Also, we are not prophets and cannot tell if your new strategy will work or not. Too many confounding factors. We interpret refusal notices because they provide concrete information.